# Cannot Configure Web Adapter After ArcGIS Server Upgrade

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-enterprise

My company just upgraded from Server 10.3 to 10.5. We are trying to configure the web adapter and keep getting errors about invalid tokens after entering in our FQDN "http://METCONAPP.METCON.DOMAIN:6080" We got this domain name from the original web adapter config file. Our default web site adapter in IIS was called "arcgis" and the installer wouldn't let us name the new adapter "arcgis," because the folder was still in the webroot. We tried to delete this web adapter from the webroot folder and start over, but we still haven't made any progress. WE're not sure how to proceed. We need to get our website and ArcGIS server back online ASAP.

Comment: When you say "start over", do you mean you uninstalled and reinstalled the web adaptor?

Comment: Yes. We confirmed that the ArcGIS server upgraded and is running, we just can't interface with it.

Comment: Did you try enabling GET for tokens?  http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/administer/windows/enable-token-acquisition-through-an-http-get-request.htm

Comment: We can't login to the server at all. We can see that it's running in the Windows Server Manager, but that's it.

Comment: Can you open http://localhost:6080/arcgis/manager or http://localhost:6080/arcgis/admin?

Comment: We cannot open either. This was all working fine before we tried to upgrade.

Comment: You'll need to call ESRI Technical Support, this happened to me as well, upgraded from 10.5 to 10.6 and nothing worked afterwards.  They were able to fix.  Hopefully your maintenance is current.

Comment: A straight upgrade from a standalone ArcGIS Server 10.3 to standalone ArcGIS 10.5? No portal in the mix right?  To diagnose further, need more info about steps, endpoints you can hit, logs from the upgrade, etc.  You upgraded the web adaptor after upgrading the GIS Server?

I would suggest rolling back to your restore point and follow these steps/order  http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/get-started/windows/upgrade-arcgis-server.htm#  Esri support might be your best bet with a remote session.